# Geting IIS applicationHost.config LogFile settings using IISAdministraton PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I've been trying to teach myself the [IISAdministration module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=win10-ps) by getting and modifying basic settings in the `applicationHost.config` file. I'm struggling to understand how to do the IISAdministration equivalent of my below example using the [WebAdministration module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=win10-ps). I'm still currently reading [this great article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation) about how IIS configuration works and I'm just not getting it.

Working WebAdministration example:

```
#Gets the Log File format set in the applicationHost.config file
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile" -Name "logFormat"
```

This is what I came up with using the IISAdministraton commands but I'm getting a "WARNING: Config collection element does not exist". The setting I'm trying to set does in fact exist so I must be doing something wrong. Any guidance or explanation would be greatly appreciated

```
$section = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/sites"

Get-IISConfigCollection $section | Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigAttribute @{"Name"="logFormat"}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found one way to access the logFormat attribute using IISAdministration. I sincerely hope this is not the natural way of accessing nested attributes in config files and I just so happen to stumble across one of many ways to achieve my goal in this module. I'm still playing with the commands and reading about them so more to come.

```
Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/sites" | Get-IISConfigElement -ChildElementName "siteDefaults" | Get-IISConfigElement -ChildElementName "logFile" | Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName "logFormat"
```

**UPDATE:**

Another way I found accessing the logFormat attribute using IISAdministration but I'm still not quite satisfied.

```
$manager = Get-IISServerManager
$config = $manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
$section = $config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites")
$siteDefaults = $section.GetChildElement("siteDefaults")
$siteDefaults.GetChildElement("logFile")["logFormat"]
```

Comment: You should assume WebAdministration obsolete and avoid using it in any of your scripts.

Comment: @LexLi I strongly disagree that anyone should assume it's obsolete. It accomplishes the exact same job that IISAdmin does but with less elegance. I will admit that the return types are way more useful when using IISAdmin returns which is partially why I'm learning IISAdministration. This is a great article regarding the subject https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell. WebAdmin is still supported in the latest versions of Windows Server

Comment: a lot of things are supported, like classic ASP but why should you keep using them when clearly the new design supersedes.

Comment: I hear you and would agree in most cases but to say that the module is obsolete is factually wrong.

Comment: @HiTech Try to use the WebAdminsitration from Powershell 7, you will then consider it obsolete

Comment: @XtianGIS Thanks. You're replying to a 5 year old post btw

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the WebAdministration memory leak issues for some time now, I'm currently working on replacing WebAdministration cmdlets with corresponding IISAdministration ones in a number of DSC modules. I'm still looking for the most efficient way to do each task and stumbled across this thread. I wanted to offer another option:

```
$sm = Get-IISServerManager
$sm.SiteDefaults.LogFile.LogFormat
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your comment drove me to find this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/ - my goal was to "check all the checkboxes" (select all the fields) and this accomplished it: $sm.Sites[$siteName].LogFile.LogExtFileFlags = "Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, SiteName, ComputerName, ServerIP, Method, UriStem, UriQuery, BytesSent, BytesRecv, TimeTaken, ProtocolVersion, Host, HttpStatus, Win32Status, ServerPort, UserAgent, HttpSubStatus, Cookie, Referer"

Answer (score 0):

HiTech/ I deleted my earlier answer after looking at this again.

As you have discovered. You cannot get directly to the element using the IISAdmin as you could with WebAdmin.

You have navigate until what you are after is exposed as an attribute or value. This is actually [detailed in the cmdlet help of Get-IISConfigElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisconfigelement?view=win10-ps) in example 1.

Modified to show output per section and to get log file format.

```
# Gets the Log File format set in the applicationHost.config file
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile" -Name "logFormat"
# W3C


# Attempt at using IISADministration to get the same information

($ConfigSection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/sites")
<#
...
ChildElements         : {siteDefaults, applicationDefaults, virtualDirectoryDefaults}
ElementTagName        : system.applicationHost/sites
...
#>
($SitesCollection = Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $ConfigSection)
<#
Attributes      : {name, id, serverAutoStart, state}
ChildElements   : {bindings, limits, logFile, traceFailedRequestsLogging...}
...
RawAttributes   : {[name, Default Web Site], [id, 1], [serverAutoStart, True], [state, 1]}
...
#>
($Site = Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $SitesCollection -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = "Default Web Site"})
<#
Attributes      : {name, id, serverAutoStart, state}
ChildElements   : {bindings, limits, logFile, traceFailedRequestsLogging...}
...}
RawAttributes   : {[name, Default Web Site], [id, 1], [serverAutoStart, True], [state, 1]}
...
#>
($Elem = Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $Site -ChildElementName "logfile")
<#
Attributes      : {logExtFileFlags, customLogPluginClsid, logFormat, logTargetW3C...}
ChildElements   : {customFields}
ElementTagName  : logFile
...
RawAttributes   : {[logExtFileFlags, 2478031], [customLogPluginClsid, ], [logFormat, 2], [logTargetW3C, 1]...}
...
#>
($LogDetails = Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $Elem -AttributeName "logformat")

# W3C
```

So you end up with this, no were near as succinct as WebAdmin construct...

```
Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/sites" | 
%{Get-IISConfigCollection -ConfigElement $PSItem} | 
%{Get-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $PSItem -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = "Default Web Site"}} | 
%{Get-IISConfigElement -ConfigElement $PSItem -ChildElementName "logfile"} | 
%{Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $PSItem -AttributeName "logformat"}

# Results 

W3C
```

And yep, the above would not give target results without the loop.

Your first update, though you were not happy with it, is the most succinct thus far. Yet even with what we've both tried. Those configs are just XML files, so just use XML cmdlets or .Net XML namespace to get to stuff.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Sadly, similar to you, my research and testing haven't come up with anything better than what's in my updates. As I continue to make my way through the module, I can foresee the need to write scripts in the future that are a hybrid of both WebAdmin and IISAdmin. I would agree with your suggestion of using the vanilla XML cmdlets. They would work great for simply retrieving information.